# Proper way to have two classes contain common code

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I have two classes with same interface that implement different APIs.

```
class RawAPI_1 {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    foo() {
        console.log('foo1')
    }
}

class RawAPI_2 {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    foo() {
        console.log('foo2')
    }
}
```

Now I need to extend these classes with methods wrapped over existing (raw) API methods to make "Extended API" classes. These extended API methods are same for both classes - they just call methods from `RawAPI_1` and `RawAPI_2` respectively. In other words, I need to have two classes `ExtendedAPI_1` and `ExtendedAPI_2` that will have a method `bar()` like this:

```
    bar() {
        console.log('Extended');
        this.foo()
    }
```

If `bar()` method is called on `ExtendedAPI_1` instance, it should call `foo()` from `RawAPI_1` and if called on `ExtendedAPI_2` instance, it should call `foo()` from `RawAPI_2`.

The solution I came up to is following:

```
class ExtendedAPI{
    constructor(raw_api) {
        this.raw_api = raw_api;
    }

    bar() {
        console.log('extended');
        this.raw_api.foo();
    }
}

class Extended_API_1 extends ExtendedAPI{
    constructor(options) {
        super(new RawAPI_1(options));
    }
}

class Extended_API_2 extends ExtendedAPI{
    constructor(options) {
        super(new RawAPI_2(options));
    }
}
```

Wondering if this is a good approach and if there are any other ways to do same thing.

Comment: Are you aware of the Adapter pattern? It seems relevant to your situation: https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/master/Structural/Adapter

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa Now, I am. Well, it seems like I did something similar to it but Adapter pattern is about interfaces and about interfaces mapping (as I understood). In my case, in extended final class I will have not just methods mapping but also new functionality with implemented code that I want to be common in both Extended_API_1 and  Extended_API_2. So I think I must be not Adapter pattern but something different.